# Authenticating different kinds of users in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm making an app with 3 kinds of users: `Teachers`, `Students` and `Admins`.

`Teachers` can *post* `Classes`, with class info and assignments and stuff, and `Students` can *enroll* in those classes and do the assignments, get the materials and stuff. The `Admins` are just the people involved in running the site and will not be taking any of those actions, but just moderating and keeping an eye on things.

My question is, how do I built the separate authentication for those three cases? The users won't have anything in common and I'm gonna need 3 different logins/sign ups from the get-go, so it's not just a matter of assigning different roles.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Do you think you can just provide a different URL for each type of user? e.g. `/teachers/register` or `/students/register`? I think you could make your life a lot easier if you only had one `users` model and provided different actions for each type.

Comment: Take a look here : https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 0):

All of those users have one important thing in common - they are all users. I don't see a reason for separating them. If you need users to sign up as a `Teacher` or `Student`, you can simply set up different views for those options and the default role that will be assigned to that user.

I don't see a reason why you think that it should be something different than assigning roles. If you really see many differences in data that will be stored for those different types of users, you can for example have have a common `Users` table and subclass them and store type-specific data in separate tables with reference to the `User`. However, for now I don't see anything in your description that can force something more than a simple role assigning.